# What is the accepted date format in mobile first adapter

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I have used date objects in pojo class, in mobile first adapter the swagger generates the json object like below.
[image]

`{
    "ID": "string",
    "date": "2016-09-28T12:30:50.723Z”, -> Date 
    "email": "string"
}`

But the way response object returns the pojo object,
Response body from api..
`{
    "ID": "string",
    "date": "1475069699667”, -> Date 
    "email": "string"
}`

[image]

Trying out api from mobilefirst swagger documentation gives back 500 error.
[image]
Looks like the what swagger showing for date and what is accepted by mobilefirst is different and there is a mismatch.

[image]

Can you please help me to know, what is the accepted date format in mobilefirst adapter?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted date format in mobilefirst adapter could be timestamp. You can try to convert your date to timestamp like this?

```
String dateOfBirth = "2016-09-28T15:59:19.172Z";  
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateOfBirth);
    long timestamp = date.getTime();
```

`timestamp` will be some thing like this `1475053159172`

Try your request again with `dateOfBirth = timestamp`

Comment: Vitbeo30, thanks for your reply.  Since the response is giving back timestamp, I tried with time stamp, but it was giving me the same 500 error("Unparseable date: \"\"",).